LTspice Error: Time step too small error
I want to simulate this circuit but in LTspice it shows this type of error. Is there a software problem or a problem in my design?

I designed this circuit for Regen clamping High side switching for Inrush protection and low side for Breaking Resistor.


Looks like a problem with your TL431 model. Can you put the model details here?

Where did you get your IC models from?  You might have the pinout of the TL431 incorrect, but without looking at the model text it's hard to know for sure.  I suggest trying to simulate the section of the circuit with just the TL431 and leave out everything else.  Regardless, you should also right-click and select real part numbers for your diode and NMOS transistors.

I simulated TL431 section only it runs sometimes well but sometimes it not. The Pin Configuration is for my purpose. I don't have any other ICs right now. So, I changed the Pin configuration for my purpose.

You didn’t answer our questions.

Please do not rate this post, its an extended comment. I use the answer option to accommodate the SPICE model here for reference
ONSEMI gives the PSPICE model for TL431 (programmable precision reference device):
This is the model from our spice lib.
SUBCKT TL431 7 6 11
*             K A FDBK
.MODEL DCLAMP D (IS=13.5N RS=25M N=1.59 
+ CJO=45P VJ=.75 M=.302 TT=50.4N BV=34V IBV=1MA)
*V1 1 6 2.495 ; used for fixed reference, replaced with EB1 Limiter
EB1 1 6 Value = { IF ( V(7,6)> 2.495, 2.495, V(7,6) ) }
R1 6 2 15.6
C1 2 6 .5U
R2 2 3 100
C2 3 4 .08U
R3 4 6 10
G2 6 8 3 6 1.73
D1 5 8 DCLAMP
D2 7 8 DCLAMP
V4 5 6 2
G1 6 2 1 11 0.11
.ENDS

As the model has a voltage dependent voltage source, EB1, written in an alternative syntax of the behavioral source B, the OP may need to promote the model to the main circuit and replace the voltage dependent voltage source EB1 with the explicit behavioral source B1 (as in the Intusoft's model but using the LTspice syntax), then tune the simulation using the tripdv/tripdt options (see LTspice's help) of the arbitrary behavioral voltage source.
Also, when doing an LTspice simulation with PSpice models, using the Gear integration method might occasionally be a better option than the modified trap.
